# How can I use shared WebSocket List on Multi Pod .Net App?

Tags: .net, kubernetes, websocket, redis

I have a .Net App which has a Websocket list. This app has 2 kubernetes pods on production. I want to use shared websocket lists for 2 pods. How can I handle this problem. Can I store my websocket list on redis?

I tried to research how to store websocket object on db level. I couldnt find solution.